# Auditing Disabled Yet AuditData Table Still Growing

Tags: 2007

We had a situation where auditing was enabled for our site collection and generating monstrous amounts of data in our database. So we finally were able to trim all of that data out and then went in and disabled all of the options under "Configure Audit Settings" on the site collection.

However, the AuditData table continues to grow at an extremely quick pace.

Is there another setting somewhere that I missed to turn auditing off?

Dana

Answer (score 1):

Is auditing perhaps enabled on one of your other site collections?

You can check this by downloading the free trial version of [this tool](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/SharePoint-Audit.aspx) and opening the Audit monitor screen in central administration, which provides a quick overview of auditing on all site collection.

No need to purchase it if you only doing this once.

Please note that I was involved n the development of this tool.